# How to test a component within a HoC?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am using `react-native-i18next` to translate multiple components within my application, more specifically this component is an example:

```
export const Header = translate('shareWith')(props =>
  (<View style={styles.header}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={props.onCancel}>
      <Text style={styles.headerAction}>
        {props.t('app:cancel')}
      </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    <Text style={styles.screenTitle}>
      {props.t('screenTitle')}
    </Text>

    <TouchableHighlight onPress={props.onDone}>
      <Text style={styles.headerAction}>
        {props.t('app:done')}
      </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
   </View>));
```

I am trying to test the `Header` component I am unable to render the component.

As per the `react-native-i18next` documents, it recommends either mocking or add a `t` prop. Neither of which works.

prop:

```
<Header {...props} t={() => {}} />
```

Mock:

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate HoC receive the t function as a prop
  translate: () => Component => props => <Component t={() => ''} {...props} />,
}));
```

Comment: What kind of test are you trying to do and which testing framework? Also, why can't you render the component?

Comment: It might be easier to extract the component that is wrapped in the `translate` in its own component and test that one directly. It's not clear exactly what the purpose of `t` is there